# Como puedo terminar de normalizar la siguiente tabla con sus columnas notas?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, laravel-9

Como puedo normalizar los campos notas de la tabla? estaba pensando en la `4fn` pero al tener 6 notas me confunde el como hacerlo, quiero seguir las mejores practicas, uso `mysql-8.0` y `laravel 9`. Cabe resaltar que de esta tabla calificacion o las que salgan despues de normalizar, pienso obtener un pdf de notas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Borras las notas y la pones en otra tabla `Notas` con `id_nota`, `id_calificacion(fk)` y `nota` y los datetimes que estimes conveniente

Comment: entiendo, y en la tabla `Notas` te refieres a dejar una sola columna `notas`? o las mismas 6 columnas que tenia en la tabla calificacion, lo sierto es que necesito 6 notas en lo posible en una sola fila.

Comment: Exacto como dices, siempre serán 6. Si no normalizo, habrá la posibilidad de que cuando la tabla `Notas` tenga miles de registros se genere latencia o delay en el crud afectando la experiencia de usuario?

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaracion. Buen negocio y buen codigo para este año.